# In H2 Database, add index while table creation in single query

Tags: sql, indexing, h2

I am trying to create table having different indexes with single query but H2 gives Error for example:

```
create table tbl_Cust
(
  id int primary key auto_increment not null, 
  fid int,
  c_name varchar(50),
  INDEX (fid)
);
```

but this gives error as

```
Unknown data type: "("; SQL statement:
[Error Code: 50004]
[SQL State: HY004]
```

Due to this I have to run 2 different queries to create table with Index. First query to create table and then second query to add index with

```
create INDEX c_fid on tbl_Cust(fid);
```

Is there something wrong in my query or H2 simply does not support this creation of table with index in single query?

Comment: There is no `index` option in the  `create table` statement which is clearly documented in the manual: http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't find the line stating that index option is not while creating table. Can you put that line here.

Comment: Look at the syntax diagram (the "graph") for the statement. There is no `index` keyword in there.

Answer (score 23):

Interesting question. The solution is even more interesting, as it involves MySQL compatibility mode.

It's actually possible to perform the exact same command you wrote **without** any modification, provided you just add to your jdbc url the MySQL mode.

Example URL like this: `jdbc:h2:mem:;mode=mysql`

SQL remains:

```
create table tbl_Cust
(
  id int primary key auto_increment not null, 
  fid int,
  c_name varchar(50),
  INDEX (fid)
);
Update count: 0
(15 ms)
```

Too bad I did not see this question earlier... Hopefully the solution might become handy one day to someone :-)

Comment: Your query is not working for me. Giving the same error mentioned in question

Comment: Please share your db URL, your sql query and the version of H2 you're using.

Comment: Thanks Christian! I'm using H2 at 1.4.193 version and it worked like a charm with MySql compatibility mode.

Comment: This does work, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I could resolve the problem. According to
http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_index
I modified the query. It works fine with my H2 server.

```sql
CREATE TABLE subscription_validator (
    application_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    api_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    validator_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (application_id,api_id),
    CONSTRAINT subscription_validator_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (validator_id) REFERENCES validator (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
  );

CREATE INDEX validator_id ON subscription_validator(validator_id);
```